# I'm trying to add a non-key column into an existing table (as the third column) won't let me without dropping table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

New data element added to existing source document.  Needs to be the third column to fit in with last three years' worth of data.  new element is not a key element.  Tried to add column, SQL says it can't without dropping and recreating table.

I want the new table to look like:

```
CUR_CLM_UNIQ_ID numeric(13, 0)  Checked
PRVDR_OSCAR_NUM varchar(6)  Checked
BENE_MBI_NUM    varchar(11) Unchecked---this is the new field
BENE_HIC_NUM    varchar(11) Checked
```

Comment: you are using the designer, right?. And you are trying to add a column between other existing columns?...the only way to do that is to drop the table and create it again. If you want to add the new column as the last column you wouldn't be having this issue (and it would be faster if you use t-sql for this)

Comment: Column order doesn't really matter, so just add it to the end.

Comment: But if I add it to the end, when I go to add the next monthly feed, how do I handle that when it will be the third column from here on out

Comment: You shouldn't have a table that needs constant adding of new columns

Comment: Thanks Lamak.  I don't think CMS will be listening to me though.

Comment: There is something majorly wrong with the design here. Column order should not matter and constantly changing the table structure is a clear sign that normalization issues are very likely.

Comment: Can you explain more about why the physical order of the columns matters to the application?  Why does "the next monthly feed" require a specific column order?

Comment: I'm just appending the information from the next monthly feed to the bottom of the existing table.  The new structure has added a new column in the third column spot (not at the end).  There are no column labels, so now the new column is labeled column 3 and has the same number and data type as the old

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, this is just the header file, and only parts of it are used.  I created a new table that will incorporate it.  It's not perfect, but it uses CMS' logic.  Thanks!

Comment: You know that you are violating a very central principle of relational design. You should add the data with another column that indicates the catergory (contents MBI or HEC) its from. But if you need to add columns using the designer you can add the new column and then highlight the column and then drag the column up or down to whatever position it in the table that you want it to be in. Another way is to create a new table with the new column where you want it to be and then insert with a select to fill the table.